# Adaptive Optics Capability in the Visible Range

Tags: optics, telescopes

Telescopes with adaptive optics (AO) have been in use for several decades. To my knowledge, the lowest wavelengths utilized are in the near-infrared. It's known that Fried parameters are smaller for visible versus infrared ranges.

> Are there any earth-based observatories utlizing AO in the visible range? What are the technical issues to achieve acceptable AO Strehl ratios in the visible range?

Comment: A brief google search leads to this 2008 proposal : http://ao.jpl.nasa.gov/Palm3K/Palm3KIndex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are rare because the size of the patch of atmosphere that can be corrected by a given guide star is so much smaller at shorter wavelengths and changes faster - so you are either limited to where you can observe (near a bright guide star), or you need complex and expensive laser guide star systems.

If you are purely imaging (rather than trying to use AO to feed a spectrograph) there is a common alternative. You image the object continually but only use those images where the atmosphere happened to be still enough to briefly give a good image. You can do this either by reading out the [CCD in short exposures](http://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/research/lucky/) or using a separate shutter. 
You can combine this with a simpler AO system to make a "good" atmosphere into an "very good" one - eg the Magellan telescope has a [visible AO system](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0146)

The other big driver against a visible AO system purely for imaging is that you can always use the Space telescope instead.

Comment: Martin, I appreciate the Magellan reference.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge in visible range making workable AO compensation system is very difficult and no earth based observation telescope exits. If we assume that acceptable S=0.8, at the near-IR wavelength range (say, 1.5 um), then the strehl ratio at visible (say, 0.5 um) is 1/3*0.8. Because the S is proportional to (wavelength)^6/5.